# Why do mozilla and webkit prepend -moz- and -webkit- to CSS3 rules?

Tags: webkit, css, mozilla, w3c, w3c-validation

CSS3 rules bring lots of interesting features.

Take [border-radius](http://www.w3.org/TR/2005/WD-css3-background-20050216/#the-border-radius), for example. The standard says that if you write this rule:

```
div.rounded-corners {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I should get a 5px border radius.

But neither mozilla nor webkit implement this. However, they implement the same thing, with the same parameters, with a different name (`-moz-border-radius` and `-webkit-border-radius`, respectively).

In order to satisfy as many browsers as possible, you end up with this:

```
div.rounded-corners {
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I can see two obvious disadvantages:

- Copy-paste code. This has obvious risks that I will not discuss here.
- The [W3C CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) will not validate these rules.

At the same time, I don't see any obvious advantages.

I believe that the people behind mozilla and webkit are more intelligent than myself. There must be some good reasons to have things structured this way. It's just that I can't see them.

So, I must ask you people: why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `-moz-border-radius` describes Mozilla's semantics. If CSS3 gets published with different semantics, then Mozilla can always implement `border-radius` using *those* semantics and they won't break anyone's website.

Meanwhile, if they just used `border-radius` directly, then if CSS3 gets published with different semantics, Mozilla has to choose between breaking people's sites, or forever supporting nonstandard CSS.

Comment: hmm. I'm not sure I follow the reasoning here. Let's assume that border-radius standard changes. And firefox creates it with the extension. Wouldn't that break the sites that have both the border-radius and the -moz-border-radius anyway? Or will they make the -moz-border-radius with the old implementation "override" the standard?

Comment: Typically the ‘old’, prefixed version is kept as an alias for a while. eg. if you set `-moz-opacity` it will set the `opacity` style, and vice-versa. Where there are syntax differences it'll convert between the formats. The syntax of `-moz-border-radius` is currently quite different from the syntax of `-webkit-border-radius` as they both implemented the feature separately; only the simple case is the same on both. This would have caused incompability problems if they had not used prefixed property names.

Answer (score 3):

They do this because its not fully supported. It much like having that code in beta. Eventually they will add support for border-radius.

It more obvious when you look at the linear gradients.

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(100% 100% 90deg, #2F2727, #1a82f7);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#1a82f7), to(#2F2727));
```

Notice they don't use the same syntax. When they finally agree on a standard then both with add support for linear-gradient and use the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Simple. The proprietary variants `-moz` and `-webkit` were there *before* the `border-radius` became written into the CSS3 recommendation. They had their own implementations but didn't know whether these would match W3C's final recommendation. Thus, they didn't use the now-official name at that point, either, so as not to break things later on.

Answer (score 2):

Note that [as of 2010-09-14](http://blog.mozilla.com/meeting-notes/archives/380), the -moz prefix has been removed from border-radius.  This means that Firefox 4 will support border-radius with no prefix.